# Which object is not serializable Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have the following code to check if a file name follows certain date-time pattern.

```
import java.text.{ParseException, SimpleDateFormat}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

class AssetFileNameConventionCheck() extends FileNameConventionCheck("""asset-created-(\\d{14}).json""".r) { //// defining regex with a dummy value

  val dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")

  private val isValidFileFormatUdf = udf((name: String) => {
    val isValid = regex.findFirstMatchIn(name) match {
      case Some(matchedPattern) =>
        val timestampString = matchedPattern.group(1) // Get the timestamp

        try {
          LocalDateTime.parse(timestampString, dtf) // Try to parse the timestamp
          true
        } catch {
          case _: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException => false
        }
      case None => false
    }
    isValid
  })

  override def check(colName: String, inputDf: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
    dateFormat.setLenient(false)


    inputDf
      .withColumn("isFileNameValidDateTime", isValidFileFormatUdf(col("name")))
  }
}

class FileNameConventionCheck(override val regex: Regex) extends StructuralCheck("isFileNameValid") {
  def check(colName: String, inputDf: DataFrame): DataFrame =
    inputDf
    .withColumn("isFileNameValid", when(col("name").rlike(regex.regex), true).otherwise(false))
}

abstract class StructuralCheck(val checkName: String) {
  val regex: Regex

  def check(colName: String, inputDf: DataFrame): DataFrame

}
```

It is raising the following exception, but I can't figure out which specific class is not serializable and why. How do I go about debugging this?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2477)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1(RDD.scala:912)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:911)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:753)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:445)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3715)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2728)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3706)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3704)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2728)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:808)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:785)
    at dna.dat.dam.datazones.RawZoneTemplate.execute(RawZoneTemplate.scala:24)
    at dna.dat.dam.start.NewDAMSparkApp$.tableRunner(NewDAMSparkApp.scala:122)
    at dna.dat.dam.start.NewDAMSparkApp$.$anonfun$new$4(NewDAMSparkApp.scala:82)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at dna.dat.dam.start.NewDAMSparkApp$.delayedEndpoint$com$tccc$dna$dat$dam$start$NewDAMSparkApp$1(NewDAMSparkApp.scala:78)
    at dna.dat.dam.start.NewDAMSparkApp$delayedInit$body.apply(NewDAMSparkApp.scala:16)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
    at dna.synapse.spark.SynapseSparkBase.main(SynapseSparkBase.scala:17)
    at dna.dat.dam.start.NewDAMSparkApp.main(NewDAMSparkApp.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: dna.dat.dam.datazones.AssetFileNameConventionCheck
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: dna.dat.dam.datazones.AssetFileNameConventionCheck, value: dna.dat.dam.datazones.AssetFileNameConventionCheck@4b9d2cee)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 1)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class dna.dat.dam.datazones.AssetFileNameConventionCheck, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic com/tccc/dna/dat/dam/datazones/AssetFileNameConventionCheck.$anonfun$isValidFileFormatUdf$1$adapted:(Lcom/tccc/dna/dat/dam/datazones/AssetFileNameConventionCheck;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;, instantiatedMethodType=(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;, numCaptured=1])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class dna.dat.dam.datazones.AssetFileNameConventionCheck$$Lambda$2740/467937204, dna.dat.dam.datazones.AssetFileNameConventionCheck$$Lambda$2740/467937204@18c0f025)
    - element of array (index: 1)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 4)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ScalaUDF.$anonfun$f$2:(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ScalaUDF;Lscala/Function1;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Expression;Lscala/runtime/LazyRef;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)Ljava/lang/Object;, instantiatedMethodType=(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)Ljava/lang/Object;, numCaptured=4])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$Lambda$2768/813768593, org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$Lambda$2768/813768593@4b62f1ba)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, name: f, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, UDF(input[0, string, true]))
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, name: canonicalized, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, UDF(input[0, string, true]))
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 2)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ScalaUDF.$anonfun$catalystConverter$3:(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ScalaUDF;Lscala/Function1;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, instantiatedMethodType=(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, numCaptured=2])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$Lambda$2770/1054998702, org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$Lambda$2770/1054998702@6e612122)
    - element of array (index: 1)
    - array (class [Lscala.Function1;, size 2)
    - element of array (index: 6)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 8)
    - element of array (index: 1)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 3)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function2.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/sql/execution/WholeStageCodegenExec.$anonfun$doExecute$4$adapted:(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/codegen/CodeAndComment;[Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/metric/SQLMetric;Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, instantiatedMethodType=(Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/collection/Iterator;)Lscala/collection/Iterator;, numCaptured=3])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$Lambda$2426/187070277, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$Lambda$2426/187070277@7aaf6bfd)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:413)
    ... 50 more
```

Comment: According to the second exception message ("Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: dna.dat.dam.datazones.AssetFileNameConventionCheck
") it is the class `AssetFileNameConventionCheck` in the package `dna.dat.dam.datazones`

Comment: That is clear, but which specific class is referenced by AssetFileNameConventionCheck or why isn't AssetFileNameConventionCheck serializable?

Comment: Neither `AssetFileNameConventionCheck` nor any of its superclasses (`FileNameConventionCheck` and `StructuralCheck`) implement `java.io.Serializable` and therefore no instances of these classes are serializable. At least `AssetFileNameConventionCheck` must implement `Serializable`.

Comment: .... and all of its fields need to be `Serializable` or `transient` ... and since the parent class is apparently not `Serializable`, it must have an accessible no-args constructor.